# How to print linked list nodes while traversing?

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I tried printing below code (temp):

```
public void insert(int val, int index){
    if(index == 0){
        insertFirst(val);
        return; 
    }
    if(index == size){
        insertLast(val);
        return;
    }

    Node temp = head;

    for(int i=1; i<index; i++){
        temp = temp.next;
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    Node node = new Node(val, temp.next);
    temp.next = node;
    size++;
}
```

But getting this output instead:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlGHI.png)

please let me know, how to resolve it, i want to see the flow!

Comment: You could either explicitly print what you want to print (which I guess would be `temp.getValue()` or something), or better still, override the `toString` method in your `Node` class, so that `System.out.println` knows how to print them.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I tried the toString method earlier, but the error is still there, not converting Node to string!